Getting error "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForN"
I'm getting the following error about 100 times out of every 1000 calls
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()
   at AirlineConnector.OmanAirways.Helpers.Helper.<ProviderCallAsync>d__12.MoveNext()A task was canceled.-   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()
   at AirlineConnector.OmanAirways.Helpers.Helper.<ProviderCallAsync>d__12.MoveNext()`

Following is my code.
We are calling this 'APICallAsync()' method in multiple places in my project.
Why I'm getting this error?
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Text;

namespace Helpers
{
    public class Helper 
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<IHttpClientFactory> httpClientFactoryLazy = new Lazy<IHttpClientFactory>(() =>
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddHttpClient("HttpClientFactory", client =>
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            })
              .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
              {
                  var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                  handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                  return handler;
              });
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        });

        private static IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory
        {
            get
            {
                return httpClientFactoryLazy.Value;
            }
        }
        public async Task<string> APICallAsync(string remoteRequest, string serviceURL, string ActionURL)
        {
            var rawResponse = "";
            try
            {
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, serviceURL);
                request.Content = new StringContent(remoteRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", ActionURL);

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
              
                var _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("HttpClientFactory");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                rawResponse = await response?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return rawResponse;
        }
    }

We are calling this 'APICallAsync()' method in multiple places.
Why I'm getting this error?

The code is full of serious bugs (never mind that SOAP isn't just a POST of an XML string) but wouldn't generate this exception because it just hides all exceptions instead of logging or handling them.

BTW I work for an OTA too and know that GDSs blocked TLS 1.1 and anything less in 2016. This is seriously broken code and no way to call complex SOAP services. It's no way to use HttpClientFactory either. Start by using HttpClientFactory the way the tutorials show instead of trying to improve it, and use at least svcutil to generate proper DTOs, if not the entire proxy. If you write code for individual airlines like this, NDC or no, the traffic isn't high enough to justify micro-optimizations. Although this code leaks HttpClient instances

The call stack shows that the error started in AirlineConnector.OmanAirways.Helpers.Helper.<ProviderCallAsync>, not APICallAsync. What does this method do? Does it forget to await a task perhaps?

@PanagiotisKanavos It is actually 'ProviderCallAsync', I have posted the rewrited code here. When I used DTO, and svcutil , It makes very huge memory and CPU utliziation in fargate/docker environment.But it is reduced when we are called apis as POST.What are the bugs here? How can I solve it? Please help

It uses a lot of RAM because airline responses are huge. The code you posted will be even slower and use even more RAM because it serializes request DTOs into strings instead of writing them directly to the request stream and then reads the responses as strings instead of deserializing them directly from the response stream. It doesn't dispose HttpClient instances which means it will keep creating more sockets on every call.

Use the svcutil proxy first to get working code. It doesn't matter how fast your code is if it can't make any call at all. If and only if you see you need better performance and after you get accustomed to how GDSs or NDC works, only then try to improve things. The real improvement won't come from using HttpClient, but deserializing only the elements you need using eg a SAX parser or XmlReader. Don't rush to use these though, because you don't know how to handle airline calls yet

@PanagiotisKanavos,  Can I use REST JSON- Airline calls using ihttpclientfactory? We are experienced a significant reduction in utilization of memory and CPU when SOAP calls converted to POST. Can I do anything in this call to avaoid this'task cancelled' error? We have about 45 airlines

@PanagiotisKanavos Is it timeout error? It is in .Net Framework 4.7.1
